# save language even if user close browser

Tags: php

I have my language files in /language/  en.php, se.php etc

Here a snippet from one file:

```
$lang = array (

    'IMAGE_NOT_FOUND' => 'Kunde ej hitta bilden.',
    'ACCOUNT_ALREADY_ACTIVATED' => 'Ditt konto har redan aktiverats.'
    ...

);
```

## Current code

```
if (isset($_GET['setlang']) && $_GET['setlang'] == 'en') include('language/en.php');
elseif (isset($_GET['setlang']) && $_GET['setlang'] == 'se') include('language/se.php');
```

How would I do to save lang for next visit even if user closes browser?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_sessions.asp) for saving data across browser requests.

Comment: The question was if they close the browser... not load a different page on the same site...

Comment: It's unclear whether they were referring to a single window out of many, or a full shutdown of the session. If the latter, then yes, a full cookie would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You would could a cookie if the user does not have to login, otherwise you could save it in the database.